# reCaptcha on webform does not present challenge if user skips it accidentally first time

Tags: webforms, captcha

So here is the flow.

1. user fills webform
2. misses to respond to reCaptcha and hits submit
3. The error appears to attend to reCaptcha
   BUT - there is no reCaptcha challenge presented again while the data user provided is saved.
4. User is left wondering how to resubmit Captcha.
5. Refresh the page is an option, but that removes the data that was saved on original user interaction and user will have to fill all elements again.

Form does use ajax, and I have tried persistence to present challenge always.
I also tried using the grecaptcha.reset(); in javascript but that on its own did not work.

Any suggestions.

Comment: I found a solution at - https://www.drupal.org/project/recaptcha/issues/2420079

The solution requires to paste the below javascript code to your pages.
And Yes it worked but is this the best and only way possible?

Comment: Code as per above comment - 
Drupal.behaviors.recapcha_ajax_behaviour = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      if (typeof grecaptcha != "undefined") {
        var captchas = document.getElementsByClassName('g-recaptcha');
        for (var i = 0; i < captchas.length; i++) {
          var site_key = captchas[i].getAttribute('data-sitekey');
          if (!$(captchas[i]).html()) {
            grecaptcha.render(captchas[i], { 'sitekey' : site_key});
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }